# Not sure about R's dbinom()

Tags: r

I am looking to use `dbinom()` in R to generate a probability. The default documentation gives `dbinom(x, size, prob, log = FALSE)`, and I understand what they all mean except the x, where x is said to be "vector of quantiles". Can anyone explain what that means in context of let's say that I would like to find the probability of obtaining the number 5 twice if I sample 10 times from the numbers 1-5. In this case the binomial probability would be

```
choose(10, 2) * (1/5)^2 * (4/5)^8
```

Answer (score 2):

In your example the "number of times you see a five" is the quantile of interest. Loosely speaking, a "quantile" is a possible value of a random variable. So if you want to find the probability of seeing a 5 `x = 2` times out of `size = 10` draws where each number has `prob = 1 / 5` of being drawn you would enter `dbinom(2, 10, 1 / 5)`.